# AnyCable : Retrieve information gRPC info on ROR App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I work to switch Action Cable to AnyCable.

I don't use cookies to identify users, I use JWT because my app provide only API.

So in case of a chat, we need to retrieve the user who send the message.

In log, I see this message1:

```
RPC Command: <AnyCable::CommandMessage: command: "subscribe", identifier: "{\"channel\":\"RoomChannel\",\"room_id\":\"566\"}", connection_identifiers: "{\"current_user\":{\"id\":\"XXXXXXXX\",\"login_time\":1589745276,\"okta_id\":\"xxxxx@gmail.com\"
```

How can I retrieve the value of the object "connection_identifiers"?

Below the current connection Class : 
`Class : module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    include Authentication

```
identified_by :current_user

def connect
  self.current_user = create_user_from_tokens

  reject_unauthorized_connection unless current_user.valid
end
```

end
end`

create_user_from_tokens > Create a user object from JWT token

And the current reception method for a new message : 
`def receive(content)
    return false unless receive_params
    return false unless conversation

```
message = content['content']

message_params = {conversation_id: @conversation.id,
                  conversation: @conversation,
                  sender_id: @connection.current_user.okta_id,
                  sender_name: @connection.current_user.name,
                  content: message}

ConversationMessageService.post message_params
```

rescue StandardError
    Rails.logger.error I18n.t('log.api.websocket.error_receive')
    render json: {error: :bad_request, error_description: I18n.t('log.api.websocket.error_receive'), error_uri: ''}, status: :bad_request
  end`

As I undertand it is impossible to retrieve @connection.

Comment: Could you please provide your connection class code?

Also, could you provide an example channel code where you want to retrieve a user?

Comment: @palkan, I have edited the post, with the code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the current user from the channel, you can use `#current_user` accessor (Rails adds this delegation for you automatically).

So, the code should be:

```rb
message_params = {conversation_id: @conversation.id,
                  conversation: @conversation,
                  sender_id: current_user.okta_id,
                  sender_name: current_user.name,
                  content: message}
```

If I understood you correctly, your `current_user` object is not an AR record but a plain Ruby class, right?

Then `current_user` in channels would simply return a JSON-encoded string, not the object.

Currently, AnyCable uses GlobalID to serialize/deserialize connection identifiers. You must add GlobalID functionality to your class to make it work with AnyCable the same way as with Action Cable. For example:

```rb
class User
  include GlobalID::Identification

  def self.find_by_gid(gid)
    new(gid.params)
  end

  def to_global_id
    super(to_h.merge!(app: :custom))
  end

  alias to_gid to_global_id
end

# setup GlobalID to correctly resolve your custom class
GlobalID::Locator.use :custom do |gid|
  gid.model_name.constantize.find_by_gid(gid)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the solution with current_user and it works well, is one of the two solutions better or more efficient?

Comment: I don't think there is a significant performance difference, so it's up to you to decide which one fits your codebase better